What are the philosophical arguments for and against modeling hypotheses as Turing machines?
In this answer here,

Now we could start with a model of reality, which says that nature randomly picks a process for generating data; the process is obtained by picking a Turing machine at random, with smaller (simpler) Turing machines more likely to be chosen than complex ones; and then nature runs the Turing machine and the data you observe is the output of that Turing machine. That's a sketch of a possible model of reality; basically, it's an assumption about how nature works.


That assumption then implies (if we fill in some details) a particular prior on hypotheses. A hypothesis amounts to a Turing machine. There will be multiple Turing machines that are all consistent with the observations (that could have produced those observations), and Bayes theorem + the prior will let you infer the posterior distribution on which of those hypotheses are most likely.


This is a possible way to obtain a prior, and it seems reasonable to me. Computer science can't tell you whether that model (that assumption) is a good model of reality. But it can help you work out the consequences of making that assumption.

What are the philosophical arguments for and against this form of modeling (especially the notion of assigning higher probabilities to smaller Turing machines)?
According to the SEP article on information, Solomonoff formalized ways like this to solve many philosophical problems, but there hasn’t been much of a response due to the technical nature of his arguments:

Hutter (2007a) and Rathmanner & Hutter (2011) enumerate a plethora of classical philosophical and statistical problems around induction and claim that Solomonoff’s theory solves or avoids all these problems. Probably because of its technical nature, the theory has been largely ignored by the philosophical community. Yet, it stands out as one of the most fundamental contributions to information theory in the twentieth century and it is clearly relevant for a number of philosophical issues, such as the problem of induction.


"should smaller Turing machines be assigned a higher prior probability?" because the "adds up to 1" condition on probability distributions is a tyrant, and so for distributions over an infinite domain one is necessarily stuck with a situation where for any epsilon > 0, there exists an N such that P(n>N) < epsilon.

@Him interesting. Could that same form of argument then be generalized to justify why we prefer simpler hypotheses (and thus Occam’s razor), with or without Turing machines to model them? Or is there another way of assigning a valid probability distribution over an infinite number of hypotheses?

"This is a possible way to obtain a prior, " is pure fiction. It might be a way for Nature to "obtain a prior", but that doesn't tell us anything. -- Solomonoffs work is relevant for induction, but induction is itself already a simplified, idealized, unrealistic way of representing knowledge acquisition and belief update. So, the main problem may not be the "technical" nature, but the simplicity of the basic assumptions.

I skimmed  Rathmanner & Hutter (2011) article -- which is interesting -- it mentions a lot of technical problems, and issues in ML -- all important -- but I didn't see many philosophical issues (apart from induction of course, plus some purely speculative and imo misleading thoughts about human cognition in general).

I found a couple of arguments against:
From https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/156738544.pdf

2.3 Inductive inference
Solomonoff induction
Solomonoff’s universal inductive inference [123, 124] is a solution to the induction problem. It combines Epicurus’ and Occam’s principles in a probabilistic
way using Bayes’ theorem [81], represents hypotheses as Turing machines, and
uses Kolmogorov complexity as a prior. The idea is that given data E, one way
to find a hypothesis H (a Turing machine) that generated E is to try all possible
hypotheses on a UTM. To adhere to Occam’s principle, Solomonoff induction assigns a prior probability to each hypothesis based on its Kolmogorov complexity.
However, Solomonoff induction is incomputable because it tries every possible
hypothesis, some of which will run forever. Because of the Halting problem,
we cannot determine beforehand that any of the hypotheses will not terminate.

From https://nunosempere.com/blog/2023/02/04/just-in-time-bayesianism/

gwern•last year
This sounds like it's analogous to stick-breaking or other nonparametric Bayesian processes, where the objects are 'hypotheses' (Turing machines?) and incrementally added as required following some rule like observations of too low likelihood or every increasingly-many timesteps.
Nuño Sempere•last year
See here: https://nunosempere.com/blog/2023/03/01/computable-solomonoff/ for a follow-up, which does consider Turing machines explicitly.
I briefly looked into stick-breaking (¿https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process#The_stick-breaking_process?). I see some similarities, and not sure what exactly you can encode on a distribution, but overall it would surprise me if these were equivalent.
Also note that interpreting "hypotheses" as Turing machines doesn't really work in practice, I think. E.g., "Putin will stop being in power by 2025" is, in a sense, a collection of Turing machines describing the worlds in which that is the case, but that level is too unwieldy for practical forecasting. I don't know if you've looked into Infrabayesianism, I'm considering allowing myself to be nerd-snipped by it and seeing if it does deal correctly with that.


Maybe ChatGPT would be more reliable than individual opinionated people? Good question. Analogy: ChatGPT is to bloggers as SEP is to individual articles / authors?
